# How to test dynamic router with react router (jest)?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

This is the route I'm trying to test:

```
class App extends {Component} {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Nav />
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/block/:id/' component={Block} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Here's what I got:

```
test('block route has commons', () => {

    const wrapper = mount(
        <MemoryRouter
            initialEntries={['/block/123']}
        >
            <App />
        </MemoryRouter>
    )

    expect(wrapper.find('Nav')).toHaveLength(1)
})
```

I get:

```
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: symbol.
```

I want to test that if I go to url /block/123/ I actually get specific components from my route. I don't want to test /block/:id/. I want to test that if I go to block/123, block/:id gets chosen.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I passed `match` as props.

```
import * as renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

const renderWithProps = (props) => {
    const defaultProps = {
        match: { params: { id: 123 } },
    };
    return renderer.create(<App {...defaultProps} {...props} />);
}

test('block route has commons', () => {
    renderWithProps({});
    expect(wrapper.find('Nav')).toHaveLength(1);
})
```

`renderWithProps` write now uses App as a component. You can take that as parameter.